# Cursor/carat jumping in all directions on iPhone text entry

Tags: javascript, ios, css, ios11

I'm developing a mobile version of a 'lexical database' for language learners to put together a group dictionary. It works fine on desktop and iPad or iPhone running Chrome, but as a WebApp on iPhone under Safari, during the new word entry process the cursor disappears then reappears far below where the learner is typing. And more unpredictable, crazy stuff

I have heard this is a common problem with Safari under Apple IOS 11, where the pop-up keyboard pushes the locations higher when it appears, but none of the proposed solutions have helped.

The arrangement of my Webapp is basically a tabular database with a CSS-governed entry form that slides out on top of it. The problem is in the entry form (text input space to enter a word, textareas for example and definition, and menus for learner's name, etc)

Further, this all works fine not only on larger devices but also on iPhones *IF* the database table beneath is not loaded. There is way too much coding to provide an example, layers and layers of css, JS, php, etc, but the routine WITH database is here https://lextutor.ca/group_lex/m/?tri=date&user=demo_lab_mod and without it here https://lextutor.ca/group_lex/m/. The slide-out menu works from a small 3-bars button top left.

Any clues toward a solution will be welcome. Or wait on Apple to fix this?

Comment: I recently discovered this problem is not IOS or iPhone specific, but Safari-on-iPhone  specific. My program works correctly on Chrome for iPhone, on Android, or on iPad
     Anyway lack of response seems to indicate this problem is not general

Comment: SO either this is no issue for anyone else or else no one has solved it. Anyway in case of the latter, here is the solution in css:

html,body{ -webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch !important; overflow: auto !important; height: 100% !important; }

From Igor Cromin
https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2016/05/20/mobile-safari-scrolling-problem-with-an-input-field-inside-a-fixed-div/